# VBA: My conditions ElseIf with <= operator are not returning true when they are expected to

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, gaussian

I am using excel and vba to find the asymmetry of a gaussian curve. My data is stored in a column.  In order to find the asymmetry I need to find the maximum (peak height) value and then find the values close to 1/10 of the max on either side of the curve. To do this I iterate once to find the max then iterate in two halves to find and set the values to a variable (closest101) corresponding to 1/10 the max. I am comparing the difference of the (1/10)max  with the value in the cell and when a smaller difference is obtained, the value in the cell is the new closest match. I am not using Vlookup or Match function because my data is very noisy.
The code for that is below:

```
'low is 1/10 max
For Each cell In halfRng
cell.Select
Debug.Print Abs(low - ActiveCell.Value)
    If Abs(fifty - ActiveCell.Value) <= difference50 Then
        difference50 = Abs(fifty - ActiveCell.Value)
        closest501 = ws.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
    ElseIf Abs(low - ActiveCell.Value) <= difference10 Then
        difference10 = Abs(low - ActiveCell.Value)
        closest101 = ws.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        Debug.Print "new lowest difference  " & difference10
    End If
Next cell
```

I am also looking for the value at half the peak height, but that works fine with the same logic.

**The problem that I am having is that the "logic" fails for values that should work. For example, a difference of 0.06 is less than the previous smallest difference which was 0.3. In this case, the ElseIf would be  true and the new *difference10* would be 0.06** but it behaves as if that condition is false. Any suggestions?

Edit:
Here is some sample data:

```
difference10 = 10000 'initial value
Low = 1
Cell.value(1) = 0.7
Abs(low - cell.value(1)) = 0.3 <= 1000
So difference10 =0.3
...
Cell.value(10)  = 0.9
Abs(low - cell.value(10)) = 0.1 <= 0.3 'fails here
difference10 =0.3 'remains unchanged
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to flip your logic around - first check the smallest difference, then the next smallest.

Comment: Are you able to post a sample set of values that cause the logic to fail? `E.g., low = 50, ActiveCell.Value = 40`, etc.

Comment: A [mcve] would help, although I think that @BigBen identified the core issue. Also, you could probably benefit from reading [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248). Your code is less readable and less efficient than it could be.